# Xpath get all text within p between two a tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to get all the text within the following `<p>` paragraph tag which is located between two `<a>` link tags. I want to get either the entire paragraph tag, or all the text within the paragraph tag. Either will work.

```
<div>
     <h3 class="mt30">
         <a href="/the-world-factbook/field/area">Area</a>
     </h3>
         <p>
              <strong>total: </strong>
              1,138,910 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>land: </strong>
              1,038,700 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>water: </strong>
              100,210 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>note:</strong> 
              includes Isla de Malpelo, Roncador Cay, and Serrana Bank
          </p>
         <a href="/the-world-factbook/field/area/country-comparison/">country comparison to the world: <!-- -->27</a>
</div>
```

I was trying something like this:

```
//a[contains(@href, "area")]/@href/following::text()[1]
```

And was then going to try to figure out how to concatenate all the text nodes together. The issue is I'm trying to scrape multiple pages that have varying amounts of text nodes within the `<p>` paragraph that is surrounded by `<a>` link tags so the number of text nodes will vary. I was hoping for a more flexible approach, thanks.

Edit - I tried @michael.hor257k's recommendation `//a[contains(@href, 'area')]/following::p[1]`and the response included more than just the initial paragraph

```
<div>
     <h3 class="mt30">
         <a href="/the-world-factbook/field/area">Area</a>
     </h3>
         <p>
              <strong>total: </strong>
              1,138,910 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>land: </strong>
              1,038,700 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>water: </strong>
              100,210 sq km
              <br>
              <br>
              <strong>note:</strong> 
              includes Isla de Malpelo, Roncador Cay, and Serrana Bank
          </p>
         <a href="/the-world-factbook/field/area/country-comparison/">country comparison to the world: <!-- -->27</a>
</div>
<div>
    <h3 class="mt30">
        <a href="/the-world-factbook/field/area-comparative">Area - comparative</a>
    </h3>
        <p>slightly less than twice the size of Texas</p>
<div>
```

Comment: Which version of XSLT or XPath do you use? Anway, if the text inside of the `p` element is what you want, I would always select the `p` element and get its string value instead of trying to select down to any text node children of the `p` element.

Comment: The input is not well-formed XML: `<br>` needs to be `<br/>`.

Comment: Martin - I am using Xpath 1.0. Michael - Input was copied directly from Chrome Developer Tools then properly indented, my apologies

Comment: Re your edit: please post a [mcve] showing a **well-formed** XML input, a complete, executable XSLT and the expected output. -- Do note that you have two `a` elements that satisfy the condition, so naturally both of the  following `p` elements will be selected for output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear. To copy the first `p` element following the `a` element of interest you could do:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//a[contains(@href, 'area')]/following::p[1]" />
```

To get only the text within the same `p` use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//a[contains(@href, 'area')]/following::p[1]" />
```

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, thanks for the comment - do you know how to do this in Xpath 1.0?

Comment: Both of the above are XSLT 1.0 instructions using an XPath 1.0 expression.

Comment: @dstow Please do not post code in comments. Either edit your question or post a new one.

Comment: Comment removed and edited the original post instead.